# AWS Lambda - Database writes not reflected by subsequent read

Tags: python, mysql, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, pymysql

I have two lambda functions, one that inserts data into a database (create_user), and another (get_users) that reads it from a MySQL database hosted on AWS RDS.

The database code for the create_user lambda looks like this (note the commit):

```py
user = ... # get user from request object

with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql.INSERT_USER, (
        user.first_name,
        user.last_name,
        user.birth_date,
        user.sex,
        user.firebase_id
    ))
    self.conn.commit()
```

And the database code for the get_users lambda:

```py
with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql.GET_ALL_USERS)
    user_rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

In both lambdas I set up my database connection outside the handler function:

```py
conn_params = db_utils.db_connection_parameters()

conn = pymysql.connect(host=conn_params['host'],
                      user=conn_params['username'],
                      password=conn_params['password'],
                      database=conn_params['name'],
                      cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ...
```

The issue is that the get_users lambda response does not contain users that were recently inserted with the create_user lambda or via MySQLWorkbench (again, remembering to call `commit`). If I connect to the database with pymysql or MySQLWorkbench, I can see that the new row was inserted, but the get_users lambda does not reflect this change for another 10 minutes or so. I'd like the results to be reflected nearly immediately.

Comment: Code in a [mre] should be complete and able to replicate the issue, not be snippets.

Comment: Your answer below is completely counter-intuitive. Unfortunately, it's no possible to assess it properly because the isolated snippets of code you've posted don't allow is to look at the interaction between the different operations. You should post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Moving the connection from outside of the lambda handler function to within it fixed the issue:

```py
conn_params = db_utils.db_connection_parameters()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    user_id = int(event['pathParameters']['id'])

    conn = pymysql.connect(host=conn_params['host'],
                      user=conn_params['username'],
                      password=conn_params['password'],
                      database=conn_params['name'],
                      cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

I don't understand why. I must be misunderstanding something about the way database connections work and what they cache.

Comment: I don't think this is caching, more like the effect of repeatable read isolation level. Non-blocking reads do not see changes done in subsequent transactions

Comment: @Shadow, thanks I'll read up on that.